# Cardscrollview/Cards in Livecard

Tags: java, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm a bit stuck here,

I just started with the basics of Glass development, is it possible to add a CardScrollView/Card to an Livecard?

It looks like it's only possible to add RemoteViews to a LiveCard but I would like to show a CardScrollView instead of coding everything in xml.

```
    CardScrollView csvCardsView; //has adapter, items,...

    RemoteViews aRV = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.card_text);
    if (mLiveCard == null) {
        mLiveCard = mTimelineManager.createLiveCard(LIVE_CARD_ID);
        mLiveCard.setViews(aRV);
        //... Action code
        mLiveCard.publish(LiveCard.PublishMode.REVEAL);
    }
```

Now I can't find out how to add my `csvCardsView` to my `mLiveCard` since `LiveCard.setViews()` only accepts RemoteViews and `RemoteViews.addViews()` also only accepts RemoteViews.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add a `CardScrollView` directly to a `LiveCard`. When viewing a `LiveCard`, the Glass timeline is handling the scrolling gestures from the touchpad and allowing a `CardScrollView` there would collide with that.

Instead, if what you're looking for is to display a `CardScrollView` when the user **taps** on a `LiveCard`, you can do that by creating an activity that has the `CardScrollView` and then set that activity as the `LiveCard`'s action.